# Cross-platform HTML5 mobile development with single codebase, including app server and native client libraries?

Tags: android, ios, html, mobile, ide

I tried Kony Studio recently at a client. How does Kony Studio compare to other IDEs/frameworks for native iphone/iPad/Android compared to HTML5 development? I am working on a cloud-based adaptive learning solution that allows students to browse knowledge, test themselves and receive automated feedback about their performance.

Answer (score 9):

Never even heard of "Kony Studio".  Website info is light and/or badly organized.  Looks like the kind of thing they sell to "business people" who then force it on their devs. Most cross platform mobile dev is bad at this point. Best bets are either Phonegap, for HTML5, or Appcelerator Titanium.  I would recommend neither, although I'd lean towards Phonegap.  It really depends on how simple your app is, though.  Complex forms/interactions don't work well with HTML5, yet anyway.  Seems to work better on iPhone, but I think that's due to more effort being put into the JS frameworks for iPhone, as well as Android fragmentation seems more visible with HTML5/JS apps for some unknown reason.

I think HTML5 based apps will eventually become more prominent, then "the standard", but today its rough.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use PhoneGap with something like jQ mobile. The market definitely moves towards good /simple standards like HTML5 and CSS. The hardware acceleration is coming into browser rendering arena and "slow HTML" is going to be over with in 2-3 years.

Stay away from KONY at all possible cost. The IDE is just a set of plugins into eclipse but here is where it all starts.

The installer that you get from them does not work everywhere (i.e. hangs on some machines). Once IDE installed, the WYSIWIG feature (UI designer) is a joke. The demos look OK but in reality it is a tedious tasks to layout widgets correctly. You end up writing versions for every screen size and channel (Android vs iOS). On Android the scaling is not handled at all, for example, run your app on Galaxy Note and see that all form layout is completely skewed. KONY 4.x does not support device pixels and relative margins and paddings at all (you specify them in PIXELS!!!).

The biggest selling point is "drag-n-drop, don't write code". In reality KONY IDE generates LUA code (4.x) that DOES NOT handle any edge cases, such as no cell network. When you build a simple app that transacts a web service and your cell signal goes down your app just hangs then crashes with internal Android error and then re-running the app does not help until you terminate the corrupted process. To do a usable app one needs to write all code by hand in LUA. There is no easy upgrade to KONY 5 - the "auto convert" tools is a marketing feature.

Answer (score 0):

So one thing to keep in mind is that Kony v4 was a complete overhaul, switching the core engine away from Lua and making Javascript the scripting language.  Kony has a very fast release schedule, and is now on version 5.5, which is a vast improvement.  There has also been the addition of a new UI design tool for Kony called Visualizer, which makes the process of creating the UI an experience that is like using a wire framing tool, but the output from Visualizer is the UI is translated directly into forms in the Kony Development platform, which makes the task of creating UI's much easier.

The real advantage of Kony is that they have a Service Level Agreement ( SLA ) that guarantees that your applications will work with new OS and platform releases within 30 days of being released to the developer community, meaning that your code is "future-proofed".  This becomes a significant accelerator to your overall development approach, as you are not saddled with having to keep updating your code for each new OS update.

Kony also has embraced a complete SDLC approach, with three distinct cloud products that are designed to work independently or together, covering UI ( Visualizer ), development ( Kony Studio ), and Management of apps and devices ( MAM and MDM ).

You can trial all the products now for free at: http://www.kony.com/trials